# Making a Less Dated UI (WPF Frameworks)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

With Windows 8 and Windows 10 out, the original set of WPF controls is beginning to look a little... dated.  I'm looking for something else, something that fits a little better in the more modern UI designs.

I've looked at mahapps.metro and Modern UI, and those seem a little drastic to me.  The TabControl is a perfect example -- I'm not fond of the unbounded blocks of text that both of those seem to use for tabs.  I prefer a bounded box.  On the other hand, in Windows 10 the default focused WPF window has a white background, while the unaltered WPF menu is has a gray background, which looks a little weird:

[image: Weird UI]

Does anyone know of any good toolkits for pre-styled WPF controls aside from the two I mentioned earlier?  Or am I more likely to get what I'm looking for by mixing and matching -- a little mahapps.metro, a little default WPF, a little custom styling?

I'm not looking to reinvent the wheel here.  I don't want to find myself endlessly writing new styles, templates, etc, and micromanaging the XAML.  There's a lot of interesting code in my project, and writing hundreds of lines of XAML is not my idea of a good time. :)

If it matters (I don't think it will, but you never know), I'm using Caliburn.Micro for my MVVM framework.

Comment: eh... this is a tough one to answer.  If you're not interested in building custom controls then sticking to the defaults seem to be best.  Each OS will update their look in time and if you're using defaults your app should update along side the OS it's written towards.  I would almost suggest just sticking with the norm if you don't wanna risk being intuitive.  Personally, I'm not a fan of any 3rd party UI styles / controls so I alone can't recommend any.

Comment: I gotta admit, it's not so much that I don't want to "risk being intuitive" so much as I'm terrible at it.  I'm a coder, not a designer, and I lack the artistic capability to design something new, as much as I want to. :)  But I know what you mean.  I might be able to pull in some of the stuff I've seen and largely stick to the defaults.

Comment: Yeah, there are some default styles built in as well that you can use to dice it up somewhat.  Silverlight use to release 'themes' you could wrap XAML with but I haven't seen that used in a while so I'm not sure it's a thing anymore.

Comment: If it's personal project feel free to hit me up on chat.  I consider myself more of a UI guy than anything and I'm a MVVM purist.  I don't mind helping out here and there.

Comment: I agree. WPF needs a refresher. But I think it will never come  (Microsoft pushing too hard for UWP). But I’m exploring some possibilities to use UWP from WPF app. Nothing concreate yet, but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root seems ok. Just need to remove “store” dependencies somehow

Answer (score 0):

> Or am I more likely to get what I'm looking for by mixing and matching -- a little mahapps.metro, a little default WPF, a little custom styling?

Yes, probably. You won't likely find a toolkit that just make all built-in controls look exactly like you want :).

Another option may to be look into the Universal Windows Platform (UWP): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/whats-a-uwp.

These are the new kind of apps that can run on any Windows 10 device including PC, tablet, phone, Xbox, HoloLens, Surface Hub and more. The controls have better support for touch and pen input and probably look more what you refer to as "modern".

WPF is still a great choice for developing traditional Windows desktop applications. And if you compare the look of the built-in controls to a classic desktop application like Visual Studio, they don't look that "out-dated". Different kind of applications serve different kind of needs and sometimes you want controls that are tailored for a user that always uses a keyboard and a mouse and sometimes you don't.